# Set env var in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to set 2 temp env vars and then run a binary.

The command is like this:

```
ENV_1=firstparam ENV_2=secondparam my_binary
```

I want to move the 2 env var assignment in a bash script and use a command like this:

```
setparams.sh my_binary
```

**setparams.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ENV_1=firstparam
ENV_2=secondparam
```

What's wrong here? Why do the vars are not being set?

Comment: The working command is *syntactic*; a command consists of optional pre-command modifiers plus the actual command. Your attempt is just a script that takes `my_binary` as an argument and ignores it, while setting variables that will disappear on exit.

Comment: Your "script" would just be `ENV_1=firstparam ENV_2=secondparam "$1"`.

Comment: What you have are variable assignments.  You are not working with environment variables at all; the variables you have are internal to the shell

Comment: @chepner Using `"$@"` rather than `"$1"` lets you pass additional arguments to the command.

Comment: @WilliamPursell In the first command in the question `ENV_1=firstparam ENV_2=secondparam my_binary` the variables are passed as environment variables to `my_binary` (but they don't persist after that).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  In `setparams.sh`, ENV_1 and ENV_2 are not environment variables. (Unless they were placed in the environment by the caller)

Comment: @KeithThompson Right. I was focusing on the example, but clearly the script should accommodate arguments to the binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're passing `my_binary` as an argument to the script, I assume you want the script to (a) set the environment variables and then (b) invoke the command you sent it.

One way to do that is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENV_1=firstparam ENV_2=secondparam "$@"
```

"$@" expands to the list of arguments you passed to the script.

If you set variables like that, they'll be inherited in the environment of any command you run *on the same command line*, but not by any subsequent commands.

If you wanted to execute more than one command with those environment variables, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENV_1=firstparam
export ENV_2=secondparam
some_command
some_other_command
```

Then `$ENV_1` and `$ENV_2` will appear in the environment of `some_command` and `some_other_command` -- but **not** in the environment of your shell after `set_params.sh` finishes.

If you want a script to set environment variables that will be available in your interactive shell, you'll have to invoke it with `. ./set_params.sh` or `source ./set_params.sh`.  (And in that case you don't need the `#!/bin/bash` at the top, since it will execute in your current shell.)

Comment: despite I was talking about env vars, I meant just set some variables for the subsequent command.

Answer (score 8):

By default all user defined variables are local. They are not exported to new processes. Use **export** command to export variables and functions

```
export ENV_1=firstparam
export ENV_2=secondparam
```

Also, instead of executing you should call **source** (built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as argument, in the current shell):

```
source setparams.sh && my_binary
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your environment variables:

**setparams.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Export environment variables
export ENV_1=firstparam
export ENV_2=secondparam

# Launch binary with its provided arguments
"$@"
```

Testing it:

```sh
./setparams.sh bash -c 'echo "$ENV_1"'
```

Output:

```
firstparam
```